# When we click "accept both changes" in vscode, Which command will be executed during merge conflict?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

I wanted to any git command for accepting both changes.(ours and theirs). Then, I am curious about how the vscode is doing that. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: I mean, press it? And it obviously keeps both changes as you see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check exactly what commands are run in the "Git" console, under the "Output" tab:

[image: A screenshot of a Git console window. At the top are 4 tabs: Problems, Output, Debug Console, and Console. The Output tab is selected. To the right of the tabs is a dropdown, with "Git" selected. There are 5 icons the the right of the drowdown. Below the header various Git commands are shown.]

In this case, VSCode doesn't run *any* Git commands to accept both changes: it just removes the conflict markers by itself.